# Why does running a script from SQLPlus not require a password?

Tags: database, oracle

I noticed its possible to run SQL scripts with Oracle's SQLPlus by providing only a username and no password. Isn't this like a horrible breach of any form of security for Oracle?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, your oracle server has [OS Authentication](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/OsAuthentication.php) enabled, this basically tells oracle to trust users already logged into the OS.